# Heroku doesnt show css after deployment (cakephp)

Tags: cakephp, heroku

As title says, after deploying code on heroku the css files doesnt work (login page and after login pages working) but all other doesnt show up css and js code.

I am using php v7.0.1 and interesting thing is that everything was find before 5-6 days. But now it doesnt work and the code is same.

I have search on the Internet and only found similair problem but for ruby app.

Does anybody have idea what is problem? Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the layout code you are using to load the CSS?

Comment: <link href="http://my-app.herokuapp.com/vendors/bower_components/animate.css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> etc. Same way for JS files

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: "cakephp/cakephp": "~3.3.2", but everything was find before 5-6 days

Comment: Does heroku force you to use a URL? Can you not use `<?= $this->Html->css(['vendors/bower_components/animate.css/animate.min.css']) ?>`

Comment: Heroku support has answered and problem was in HTTPS certificate from Heroku site. Website still use HTTP protocol (Mixed Content) and https conection require HTTPS so if I manually add https to each CSS file it is working.... However thank you for your time!